# is need to use seprated Authontication system in django for ecommerce website?

Tags: python, django, api

I am create  a e-commerce website,back-end with Django and front-end with reactjs
how sprate website admin  user from eCommerce customer user  in Django ?
i use firebase auth for e-commerce frontend

Answer (score 0):

django have admin site itself. you can access it through 'localhost:8000/admin'. for more configs read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/) ;